# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near 'tblemployees' '[' 'empid' in table name

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

```
create table tblemployees
[ empid int,
empname string,
location string,
salary double1
row formate delimited fields terminated by "."]
```

I'm getting a error for the above code as

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near 'tblemployees' '[' 'empid' in table name
```

what will be the solution for this??

Comment: If you are creating table in Hive remove "["

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets "(" instead of square brackets "["..